# [Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener due to target being treated as passive

Tags: javascript, html, browser, gis

Here is a piece of code where this error occurs. I need to fix it, but I don't understand it. Please help me how I can fix this.

```
/\*\*
\* Method: stop
\* Stops an event from propagating.
\*
\* Parameters:
\* event - {Event}
\* allowDefault - {Boolean} If true, we stop the event chain but
\*                               still allow the default browser
\*                               behaviour (text selection, radio-button
\*                               clicking, etc)
\*                               Default false
\*/

stop: function(event, allowDefault) {

        if (!allowDefault) { 
            if (event.preventDefault) {
                event.preventDefault(); -there is a mistake here
            } else {
                event.returnValue = false;
            }
        }
                
        if (event.stopPropagation) {
            event.stopPropagation();
        } else {
            event.cancelBubble = true;
        }
    },
```

I'm afraid to delete or add anything because I'm not a programmer and there's no one to help me if anything happens.

Comment: It might help if you provided  sufficient HTML and the code used to create your scenario so that a working example could be created.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fauwFktktr0ff92K4Dj4j-s9mZjNyPik/view?usp=sharing